# How to update variable values after an event in a fast way?

Tags: r, performance

I want to update the values of a variable `o` after an event `r` occurred in year `y`. A `lapply()` solution seems to be quite slow with > 500k rows. Hence, looking for a faster solution I tried to avoid subsetting by using `aggregate()`, it's a little faster, but not as much as expected. Is there a faster way to do such things in `base R` (or maybe in `data.table`)?

**Example**

```
# lapply
lapply(split(df2, df2$id), function(x) {
  ry <- x$y[which(x[, "r"] == 1)]
  x[x$y >= ry, "o"] <- 1
  x
})

# aggregate
df2 <- merge(df1, with(df1, aggregate(list(ry=r), by=list(id=id), 
                    function(x) y[which(x == 1)])))
lapply(split(df2, df2$id), function(x) {
  x$o[x$y >= unique(x$ry)] <- 1
  x
})
```

```
# Output for id `11`
  id   ry    y o r
1 11 2003 2005 1 0
2 11 2003 2004 1 0
3 11 2003 2003 1 1
4 11 2003 2002 0 0
5 11 2003 2001 0 0
```

**Benchmark**

```
Unit: microseconds
      expr     min      lq     mean  median       uq      max neval cld
    lapply 915.181 929.724 988.2273 934.699 943.2465 5150.221   100   b
 aggregate 790.418 803.175 844.8039 810.192 817.4635 3474.984   100  a
```

**Data**

```
df1 <- structure(list(id = c(11, 11, 11, 11, 11, 22, 22, 22, 22, 22, 
33, 33, 33, 33, 33, 44, 44, 44, 44, 44, 55, 55, 55, 55, 55), 
    y = c(2005L, 2004L, 2003L, 2002L, 2001L, 2005L, 2004L, 2003L, 
    2002L, 2001L, 2005L, 2004L, 2003L, 2002L, 2001L, 2005L, 2004L, 
    2003L, 2002L, 2001L, 2005L, 2004L, 2003L, 2002L, 2001L), 
    o = c(0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 
    0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0), r = c(0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 
    0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1)), out.attrs = list(
    dim = c(id = 5L, y = 5L, o = 1L, r = 1L), dimnames = list(
        id = c("id=11", "id=22", "id=33", "id=44", "id=55"), 
        y = c("y=2001", "y=2002", "y=2003", "y=2004", "y=2005"
        ), o = "o=0", r = "r=0")), row.names = c(NA, -25L), class = "data.frame")
```

Comment: Using data.table I would try something like `library(data.table) ; setDT(df1) ; df1[df1[r == 1], o := 1, on = .(id, y >= y)]`. Btw, I wouldn't benchmark anything on such small data sets. microseconds benchmark are pretty much worthless in R

Comment: Another way doing this with data.table could be `setDT(df1)[, o := (y >= y[r == 1]) + 0, by = id]`

Comment: @DavidArenburg Thanks, but seems to be even slower.

Comment: Ah, I wasn't informed that you updated the comment. You're right I'll start another benchmark.

Comment: @DavidArenburg Fascinating, I didn't even notice that the task was done, never mind the benchmark! How exactly is that possible?

Comment: I guess it's a simple task for data.table. I would guess dplyr will achieve similar performance.